# Как передать путь к картинке в AngularJS для Django REST?

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

Как передать в функцию или получить внутри функции полный путь к картинке?
В итоге мне нужно передать путь к этой картинке на сервер, чтобы там Django REST мог найти этот файл в файловой системе.

```
<img ng-src="/media/{{ photo }}" />
```

где `photo` - это имя файла картинки

В итоге путь к картинке преобразуется в `http://имя_сайта/media/название_файла`

Здесь же, в другом теге используется функция `myfunc(photo)`
т.е. на вход она получает значение имени файла картинки.

Реальный путь к директории media прописан в переменной `MEDIA_ROOT` в `settings.py`. Если, предположим, я передам в REST путь к картинке в виде `'имя_файла'`, то останется получить внутри API значение переменной `MEDIA_ROOT`, как это сделать?

Если я правильно понимаю, в REST API нужно получить `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, request.data['image_url'])`, где `image_url = имя_файла`

Comment: Пожалуйста, опубликуйте найденное решение в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы передать путь к картинке из `AngularJS` в `Django REST`, 
необходимо отправить имя картинки из `AngularJS` посредством http-запроса в API на стороне сервера, и взять `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, request.data['image_url'])`, где `image_url` - имя файла, `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` - содержит значение переменной `MEDIA_ROOT` из файла настроек `settings.py` для Django.